# Paginação com Eager Loading no Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, paginação, classificação

Estou tendo um pequeno problema de ordenação envolvendo paginação e Eager Loading.

O que eu preciso fazer:

- Em uma parte do meu site, eu preciso trazer resultados paginados de uma subcategoria
- A subcategoria é filha de uma categoria, então eu tenho que exibir em uma tabela o pai que é a categoria, a subcategoria e os outros dados dela.
- Estou usando Eager Loading para trazer a categoria

O problema é que eu preciso ordenar pelo nome da categoria, e depois pelo nome da subcategoria, e os dados não estão sendo ordenados corretamente.

Segue o código:

```
// EloquentSubcategoria
public function byPage($page=1, $limit=10)
{
    $result = new \StdClass;
    $result->page = $page;
    $result->limit = $limit;
    $result->totalItems = 0;
    $result->items = array();

    $obj = $this->subcategoria->with(array('categoria' => function ($query) 
            {
                $query->orderBy('categoria.cat_nome', 'ASC');
            }))
            ->orderBy('subcategoria.sbc_nome', 'ASC');

    $articles = $obj->skip( $limit * ($page-1) )
                    ->take($limit)
                    ->get();


    $result->totalItems = $this->totalSubcategorias();
    $result->items = $articles->all();

    return $result;
}

protected function totalSubcategorias()
{
    return $this->subcategoria->count();
}


// SubcategoriaController
public function index()
{
    // Valores inteiros definidos no app
    $page = Input::get('page', 1);
    $perPage = Config::get('app.perPage');

    // retorna dados para paginacao
    $pagiData = $this->subcategoria->byPage($page, $perPage);

    // paginar
    $subcategorias = Paginator::make($pagiData->items, $pagiData->totalItems, $perPage);

    return View::make('subcategorias.index')->with('subcategorias', $subcategorias);
}
```

Comment: O problema foi resolvido.

`$this->subcategoria->with('categoria')....`

Nos modelos, a subcategoria está com um relacionamento "belongsTo" Categoria.

Mas no meu caso, eu não posso usar o belongsTo, pois ele vai retornar apenas um.

Para resolver, eu utilizei o JOIN ao invés do Eager Loading

O código ficou o seguinte:

`$query = $this->subcategoria->join('categoria', 'cat_id', '=', 'sbc_cat_id')....`

Comment: Mas para um caso oposto, o código acima iria funcionar, só alterar de subcategorias para categorias: `$this->categoria->with(array('subcategoria' => function ($query) 
            {
                $query->orderBy('subcategoria.sbc_nome', 'ASC');
            }))
            ->orderBy('categoria.cat_nome', 'ASC');`

Pois a relação e de 1-n entre Categorias e Subcategorias.
Me desculpem se eu não consegui ser mais claro, eu não sou muito bom para explicar as coisas xD.

Comment: Coloque sua solução como resposta e aceite ela. Assim fica organizado para ajudar outras pessoas que passaram pelo mesmo problema e você ainda pode ganhar reputação com isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No meu caso, eu tenho um relacionamento entre Categorias e Subcategorias

**Categorias hasMany Subcategorias**

**Subcategorias belongsTo Categorias**

Para trazer os resultados em ordem alfabética (Nome da categoria seguido de nome da subcategoria) da forma como está no meu código, não irá funcionar:

```
$obj = $this->subcategoria->with(array('categoria' => function ($query) 
{
    $query->orderBy('categoria.cat_nome', 'ASC');
}))
->orderBy('subcategoria.sbc_nome', 'ASC');
```

Pois a Subcategoria BelongsTo Categoria (isto retorna apenas um registro)

Mas se for feito ao contrário, irá funcionar

```
$obj = $this->categoria->with(array('subcategoria' => function ($query) 
{
    $query->orderBy('subcategoria.sbc_nome', 'ASC');
}))
->orderBy('categoria.cat_nome', 'ASC');
```

Porém, no final eu acabei optando por utilizar **JOIN**.

Pois no meu caso... na estrutura da minha aplicação, fazer como está escrito acima iria aumentar muito a quantidade de código que eu iria ter que adicionar, então a estrutura final que eu acabei utilizando é a seguinte:

```
public function byPage($page=1, $limit=10)
{
    $result = new \StdClass;
    $result->page = $page;
    $result->limit = $limit;
    $result->totalItems = 0;
    $result->items = array();

    $query = $this->subcategoria
            ->select('cat_nome', 'sbc_id', 'sbc_nome')
            ->join('categoria', 'cat_id', '=', 'sbc_cat_id')
            ->orderBy('cat_nome', 'ASC')
            ->orderBy('sbc_nome', 'ASC');

    $articles = $query->skip( $limit * ($page-1) )
                    ->take($limit)
                    ->get();


    $result->totalItems = $this->totalSubcategorias();
    $result->items = $articles->all();

    return $result;
}
```